# Регулярные выражения для проверки правильности хэштегов и их обработка

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как я знаю, хэштеги должны начинаться с (#) и могут состоять только из русских букв(аА-яЯ), из английских букв(aA-zZ), из цифр (0-9). Максимальное кол-во символов - 30. И еще хэштеги не могут состоять только из цифр. Эти проверки и их обработку надо реализовать на js. Помогите.

Comment: А в чем вопрос/проблема? SO создан не для того, чтобы полностью писать код за кого-то.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^#(?=.*[^0-9])[a-zа-яё0-9]{1,29}$/i
```

Comment: Только не помешало бы использовать модификатор \u чтобы русские буквы нормально работали

Comment: @ActivX в JavaScript нет модификатора u

Comment: @ActivX, во-первых, русские и так нормально работают, `u` нужен для иероглифов всяких. Во-вторых, `u` - это ES6 и, если не ошибаюсь, нигде кроме FF не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за информацию, в php применяется \u для доступа к utf таблицам

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте код

   ```
   /(^#[a-zа-яё0-9]{1,30})/i
   ```

код

```
var re = /(^#[a-zа-яё0-9]{1,30})/i; 
var reNumber = /(^#[0-9]{1,30})/i; 
var str = '#Алибабаfjd4Ali';
var m;
var mNumber;

if (((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) && 
     ((mNumber = reNumber.exec(str)) === null)) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Попробуйте это.

Comment: Зачем `g`? Где русские буквы? Где ограничение дины? Почему пробельные символы? Что за копипаст первой попавшейся регулярки?

Comment: @Qwertiy я вообще несколько удивлён, что вижу целых два ответа на вопрос, в котором не продемонстрировано ни единой попытки решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется сделать самому то можно написать их , там ничего особо страшного нету
онлайн тестировка, например [эта](http://regexr.com/) и справка по самому regexp, например та-же [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) или [JS.ru](http://javascript.ru/Regexp)